# Python unicode to float error

Tags: python, html, unicode, beautifulsoup, extract

I have a python script that extracts data from an HTML page. In the HTML there is a table that has floats. When I do a `findAll` and assignment statement it assigns it to a variable of type unicode. But I need the variable to be of type float. I thought that I could just do a `float()` conversion, but that's throwing an error:

```
  File "percentages.py", line 52, in <module>
    top_score = float(row.findAll('td')[2].text.strip())
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 62.4%
```

The code snippet looks like this:

```
for link in stat_links:
    r = requests.get(link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
    table = soup.find('table', class_="tr-table datatable scrollable")
    team_rows = table.findAll('tr')
    team_rows = team_rows[1:]
    for row in team_rows:
        if row.findAll('td')[0].text.strip() == '1':
            top_score = float(row.findAll('td')[2].text.strip())
        if row.findAll('td')[0].text.strip() == '351':
            lowest_score = float(row.findAll('td')[2].text.strip())

for row in team_rows:
    if row.findAll('td')[1].text.strip() == sys.argv[1]:
        temp = float(row.findAll('td')[2].text.strip())
        if link == "https://www.teamrankings.com/ncaa-basketball/stat/average-scoring-margin":
            top_score = top_score + abs(lowest_score)
            temp = temp + abs(lowest_score)
            lowest_score = 0
        temp = (temp - lowest_score) / (top_score - lowest_score)
        team_one = team_one + temp
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just *replace the `%` sign with an empty string*:

```
top_score = float(row.findAll('td')[2].text.strip().replace("%", ""))
```